# C# vector library

Tags: c#, performance, coordinate-system

I have been working on a vector library for a little bit now. And at this point the basics are down and I am looking for some tips and advic - this may include:

1. suggestions for things that might be missing and should be added
2. improvements for readability and of-course efficiency
3. if you have an important tip or advice that I didn't think of, please feel free to add it :)

See the code below for a `Vector3` struct and a `VectorX` struct. I have left out the Vector2, 4 for now because those are build in the exact same way as `Vector3`. `VectorX` is a struct for vectors which have no predefined length. See code below:

Vector3:

```
using System;

namespace Development
{
    public struct Vector3 : IEquatable<Vector3>
    {
        public float X { get; set; }
        public float Y { get; set; }
        public float Z { get; set; }
        public int VectorCount { get { return 3; } }

        public Vector3(float value)
        {
            X = value;
            Y = value;
            Z = value;
        }

        public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;
        }

        public Vector3(Vector3 vector)
        {
            X = vector.X;
            Y = vector.Y;
            Z = vector.Z;
        }

        public Vector3(float[] arr)
        {
            X = arr[0];
            Y = arr[1];
            Z = arr[2];
        }

        public Vector3(float[] arr, int startIndex)
        {
            if (startIndex > arr.Length - 3) { throw new Exception("start index doesnt leave enough space to fill all vector parameters"); }
            else
            {
                X = arr[startIndex];
                Y = arr[startIndex + 1];
                Z = arr[startIndex + 2];
            }
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "<" + X + ", " + Y + ", " + Z + ">";
        }

        public float[] ToArray()
        {
            return new float[] { X, Y, Z };
        }

        public Vector3 UpdateFromArray(float[] arr)
        {
            if (arr.Length < 3) throw new Exception("Array is too small to convert to vector");
            else
            {
                X = arr[0];
                Y = arr[1];
                Z = arr[2];
            }
            return this;
        }

        public Vector3 UpdateFromArray(float[] arr, int startIndex)
        {
            if (startIndex + 2 > arr.Length - 1) throw new Exception("startindex is too high to fill vector");
            else
            {
                X = arr[startIndex];
                Y = arr[startIndex + 1];
                Z = arr[startIndex + 2];
            }
            return this;
        }

        public bool Equals(Vector3 other) // not implemented
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Vector3 Abs()
        {
            X = (X < 0) ? X *= -1 : X;
            Y = (Y < 0) ? Y *= -1 : Y;
            Z = (Z < 0) ? Z *= -1 : Z;
            return this;
        }

        public float Length()
        {
            return MathF.Sqrt(MathF.Pow(X, 2) + MathF.Pow(Y, 2) + MathF.Pow(Z, 2));
        }

        public float Dist(Vector3 other)
        {
            return MathF.Sqrt(MathF.Pow((this.X - other.X), 2) + MathF.Pow((this.Y - other.Y), 2) + MathF.Pow((this.Z - other.Z), 2));
        }

        public Vector3 Min(Vector3 min)
        {
            this.X = (this.X < min.X) ? this.X : min.X;
            this.Y = (this.Y < min.Y) ? this.Y : min.Y;
            this.Z = (this.Z < min.Z) ? this.Z : min.Z;
            return this;
        }

        public Vector3 Max(Vector3 max)
        {
            this.X = (this.X > max.X) ? this.X : max.X;
            this.Y = (this.Y > max.Y) ? this.Y : max.Y;
            this.Z = (this.Z > max.Z) ? this.Z : max.Z;
            return this;
        }

        public Vector3 Clamp(Vector3 min, Vector3 max)
        {
            this.X = (this.X < min.X) ? min.X : this.X = (this.X > max.X) ? max.X : this.X;
            this.Y = (this.Y < min.Y) ? min.Y : this.Y = (this.Y > max.Y) ? max.Y : this.Y;
            this.Z = (this.Z < min.Z) ? min.Z : this.Z = (this.Z > max.Z) ? max.Z : this.Z;
            return this;
        }

        public Vector3 Lerp(Vector3 to, float amount)
        {
            amount = Math.Clamp(amount, 0, 1);
            this.X = (this.X - to.X) * amount + to.X;
            this.Y = (this.Y - to.Y) * amount + to.Y;
            this.Z = (this.Z - to.Z) * amount + to.Z;
            return this;
        }

        public Vector3 Normalize()
        {
            float scalar = 1 / MathF.Sqrt(MathF.Pow(X, 2) + MathF.Pow(Y, 2) + MathF.Pow(Z, 2));
            X *= scalar;
            Y *= scalar;
            Z *= scalar;
            return this;
        }

        public float Dot(Vector3 other)
        {
            return this.X * other.X + this.Y * other.Y + this.Z * other.Z;
        }


        public static Vector3 Abs(Vector3 value)
        {
            return value.Abs();
        }

        public static Vector3 Clamp(Vector3 value, Vector3 min, Vector3 max)
        {
            return value.Clamp(min, max);
        }

        public static Vector3 Min(Vector3 value, Vector3 min)
        {
            return value.Min(min);
        }

        public static Vector3 Max(Vector3 value, Vector3 max)
        {
            return value.Max(max);
        }

        public static float Dist(Vector3 value1, Vector3 value2)
        {
            return value1.Dist(value2);
        }

        public static float Dot(Vector3 value1, Vector3 value2)
        {
            return value1.Dot(value2);
        }

        public static float Length(Vector3 value)
        {
            return value.Length();
        }

        public static Vector3 Lerp(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, float amount)
        {
            return from.Lerp(to, amount);
        }

        public static Vector3 Normalize(Vector3 value)
        {
            return value.Normalize();
        }


        public static Vector3 Zero { get { return new Vector3(0); } }
        public static Vector3 Unit { get { return new Vector3(1); } }
        public static Vector3 UnitX { get { return new Vector3(1, 0, 0); } }
        public static Vector3 UnitY { get { return new Vector3(0, 1, 0); } }
        public static Vector3 UnitZ { get { return new Vector3(0, 0, 1); } }


        public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 left, float value)
        {
            left.X += value;
            left.Y += value;
            left.Z += value;
            return left;
        }

        public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
        {
            left.X += right.X;
            left.Y += right.Y;
            left.Z += right.Z;
            return left;
        }

        public static Vector3 operator -(Vector3 left)
        {
            left.X = (-left.X);
            left.Y = (-left.Y);
            left.Z = (-left.Z);
            return left;
        }

        public static Vector3 operator -(Vector3 left, float value)
        {
            left.X -= value;
            left.Y -= value;
            left.Z -= value;
            return left;
        }

        public static Vector3 operator -(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
        {
            left.X -= right.X;
            left.Y -= right.Y;
            left.Z -= right.Z;
            return left;
        }

        public static Vector3 operator /(Vector3 left, float value)
        {
            left.X /= value;
            left.Y /= value;
            left.Z /= value;
            return left;
        }

        public static Vector3 operator /(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
        {
            left.X /= right.X;
            left.Y /= right.Y;
            left.Z /= right.Z;
            return left;
        }

        public static Vector3 operator *(Vector3 left, float value)
        {
            left.X *= value;
            left.Y *= value;
            left.Z *= value;
            return left;
        }

        public static Vector3 operator *(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
        {
            left.X *= right.X;
            left.Y *= right.Y;
            left.Z *= right.Z;
            return left;
        }

        // do these size comparisions make sense?
        public static bool operator <(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
        {
            return (left.Length() < right.Length()) ? true : false;
        }

        public static bool operator >(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
        {
            return (left.Length() > right.Length()) ? true : false;
        }

        public static bool operator >=(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
        {
            return (left.Length() >= right.Length()) ? true : false;
        }

        public static bool operator <=(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
        {
            return (left.Length() <= right.Length()) ? true : false;
        }
        // end question

        public static bool operator ==(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
        {
            return (left.X == right.X && left.Y == right.Y && left.Z == right.Z) ? true : false;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
        {
            return (left.X != right.X || left.Y != right.Y || left.Z != right.Z) ? true : false;
        }

    }
}
```

VectorX:

```
using System;

namespace Development
{
    public struct VectorX : IEquatable<VectorX>
    {
        // private float[] VectorValues;
        public float[] VectorValues { get; set; }
        public int VectorCount { get; private set; }

        public VectorX(int vectorCount)
        {
            VectorValues = new float[vectorCount];
            VectorCount = vectorCount;
        }

        public VectorX(int vectorCount, float defaultValue)
        {
            VectorCount = vectorCount;
            VectorValues = new float[vectorCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < vectorCount; i++)
            {
                VectorValues[i] = defaultValue;
            }

        }

        public VectorX(params float[] values)
        {
            VectorValues = values;
            VectorCount = values.Length;
        }

        public VectorX(float[] arr, int startIndex)
        {
            VectorCount = arr.Length - 1 - startIndex;
            VectorValues = new float[VectorCount];
            for (int i = startIndex; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                VectorValues[i - startIndex] = arr[i];
            }
        }

        public VectorX(float[] arr, int startIndex, int endIndex)
        {
            VectorCount = endIndex - startIndex;
            VectorValues = new float[VectorCount];
            for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
            {
                VectorValues[i - startIndex] = arr[i];
            }
        }

        public VectorX(VectorX vector)
        {
            VectorCount = vector.VectorCount;
            VectorValues = vector.VectorValues;
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            string ret = "<";
            for (int i = 0; i < VectorCount; i++)
            {
                if (i == VectorCount - 1) ret += VectorValues[i];
                else ret += VectorValues[i] + ", ";
            }
            return ret += ">";
        }

        public float[] ToArray()
        {
            return VectorValues;
        }

        public VectorX UpdateFromArray(float[] arr)
        {
            if (arr.Length < VectorCount) throw new Exception("Array is too small to convert to vector");
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    VectorValues[i] = arr[i];
                }
            }
            return this;
        }

        public VectorX UpdateFromArray(float[] arr, int startIndex)
        {
            if (startIndex + VectorCount > arr.Length - 1) throw new Exception("startindex is too high to fill vector");
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    VectorValues[i] = arr[startIndex + i];
                }
            }

            return this;
        }

        public float GetAt(int pos)
        {
            if (pos >= VectorCount || pos < 0) throw new Exception("Supplied position is too large or less then 0");
            else return VectorValues[pos - 1];
        }

        public VectorX SetAt(int pos, float value)
        {
            if (pos >= VectorCount || pos < 0) throw new Exception("Supplied position is too large or less then 0");
            else
            {
                VectorValues[pos - 1] = value;
                return this;
            }
        }

        public bool Equals(VectorX other) // not implemented
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public float Length()
        {
            float total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < VectorCount; i++)
            {
                total += MathF.Pow(VectorValues[i], 2);
            }
            return MathF.Sqrt(total);
        }

        public VectorX Normalize()
        {
            float scalar = 1 / this.Length();
            for (int i = 0; i < VectorCount; i++)
            {
                VectorValues[i] *= scalar;
            }
            return this;
        }

        public VectorX Abs()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VectorCount; i++)
            {
                VectorValues[i] = (VectorValues[i] < 0) ? VectorValues[i] *= -1 : VectorValues[i];
            }
            return this;
        }

        public float Dist(VectorX other)
        {
            if (other.VectorCount != this.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors are not of same length");
            else
            {
                float sqrtValue = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < this.VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    sqrtValue += MathF.Pow((this.VectorValues[i] - other.GetAt(i)), 2);
                }
                return MathF.Sqrt(sqrtValue);
            }
        }

        public VectorX Min(VectorX min)
        {
            if (min.VectorCount != this.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors are not of same length");
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    this.VectorValues[i] = (this.VectorValues[i] > min.GetAt(i)) ? this.VectorValues[i] : min.GetAt(i);
                }
            }
            return this;
        }

        public VectorX Max(VectorX max)
        {
            if (max.VectorCount != this.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors are not of same length");
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    VectorValues[i] = (VectorValues[i] < max.GetAt(i)) ? VectorValues[i] : max.GetAt(i);
                }
            }
            return this;
        }

        public VectorX Clamp(VectorX min, VectorX max)
        {
            if (max.VectorCount != VectorCount || min.VectorCount != VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors are not of same length");
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    VectorValues[i] = (VectorValues[i] < min.GetAt(i)) ? min.GetAt(i) : VectorValues[i] = (VectorValues[i] > max.GetAt(i)) ? max.GetAt(i) : VectorValues[i];
                }
                return this;
            }
        }

        public VectorX Lerp(VectorX to, float amount)
        {
            if (to.VectorCount != VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors have different length");
            else
            {
                amount = Math.Clamp(amount, 0, 1);
                for (int i = 0; i < VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    VectorValues[i] = (VectorValues[i] - to.GetAt(i)) * amount + to.GetAt(i);
                }
                return this;
            }

        }

        public float Dot(VectorX other)
        {
            if(other.VectorCount != VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors are not the same length");
            else{
                float d = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    d += VectorValues[i] * other.GetAt(i);
                }
                return d;
            }

        }


        public static VectorX NewUnit(int size)
        {
            return new VectorX(size, 1);
        }
        public static VectorX NewUnitIndex(int size, int index)
        {
            VectorX vec = new VectorX(size);
            vec.SetAt(index, 1);
            return vec;
        }


        public static float Length(VectorX vector)
        {
            return vector.Length();
        }

        public static VectorX Normalize(VectorX vector)
        {
            return vector.Normalize();
        }

        public static VectorX Abs(VectorX vector)
        {
            return vector.Abs();
        }

        public static float Dist(VectorX vector1, VectorX vector2)
        {
            return vector1.Dist(vector2);
        }

        public static VectorX Min(VectorX vector, VectorX min)
        {
            return vector.Min(min);
        }

        public static VectorX Max(VectorX vector, VectorX min)
        {
            return vector.Max(min);
        }

        public static VectorX Clamp(VectorX vector, VectorX min, VectorX max)
        {
            return vector.Clamp(min, max);
        }

        public static VectorX Lerp(VectorX vector, VectorX to, float amount)
        {
            return vector.Lerp(to, amount);
        }

        public static float Dot(VectorX vector1, VectorX vector2)
        {
            return vector1.Dot(vector2);
        }


        public static VectorX operator +(VectorX left, float value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
            {
                left.SetAt(i, left.GetAt(i) + value);
            }
            return left;
        }

        public static VectorX operator +(VectorX left, VectorX right)
        {
            if(left.VectorCount != right.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors not same length");
            else{
                for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    left.SetAt(i, left.GetAt(i) + right.GetAt(i));
                }
                return left;
            }
        }

        public static VectorX operator -(VectorX left)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
            {
                left.SetAt(i, left.GetAt(i) * -1);
            }
            return left;
        }

        public static VectorX operator -(VectorX left, float value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
            {
                left.SetAt(i, left.GetAt(i) - value);
            }
            return left;
        }

        public static VectorX operator -(VectorX left, VectorX right)
        {
            if(left.VectorCount != right.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors not same length");
            else{
                for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    left.SetAt(i, left.GetAt(i) - right.GetAt(i));
                }
                return left;
            }
        }

        public static VectorX operator /(VectorX left, float value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
            {
                left.SetAt(i, left.GetAt(i) / value);
            }
            return left;
        }

        public static VectorX operator /(VectorX left, VectorX right)
        {
            if(left.VectorCount != right.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors not same length");
            else{
                for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    left.SetAt(i, left.GetAt(i) / right.GetAt(i));
                }
                return left;
            }
        }

        public static VectorX operator *(VectorX left, float value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
            {
                left.SetAt(i, left.GetAt(i) * value);
            }
            return left;
        }

        public static VectorX operator *(VectorX left, VectorX right)
        {
            if(left.VectorCount != right.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors not same length");
            else{
                for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    left.SetAt(i, left.GetAt(i) * right.GetAt(i));
                }
                return left;
            }
        }

        // do these size comparisions make sense?
        public static bool operator <(VectorX left, VectorX right)
        {
            if(left.VectorCount != right.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors not same length");
            else return (left.Length() < right.Length()) ? true : false;
        }

        public static bool operator >(VectorX left, VectorX right)
        {
            if(left.VectorCount != right.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors not same length");
            else return (left.Length() > right.Length()) ? true : false;
        }

        public static bool operator >=(VectorX left, VectorX right)
        {
            if(left.VectorCount != right.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors not same length");
            else return (left.Length() >= right.Length()) ? true : false;
        }

        public static bool operator <=(VectorX left, VectorX right)
        {
            if(left.VectorCount != right.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors not same length");
            else return (left.Length() <= right.Length()) ? true : false;
        }
        // end question

        public static bool operator ==(VectorX left, VectorX right)
        {
            if(left.VectorCount != right.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors not same length");
            else 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    if(left.GetAt(i) != right.GetAt(i)) return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        public static bool operator !=(VectorX left, VectorX right)
        {
            if(left.VectorCount != right.VectorCount) throw new Exception("Vectors not same length");
            else 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < left.VectorCount; i++)
                {
                    if(left.GetAt(i) != right.GetAt(i)) return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems alot like a javascript library (three.js) ported to C#.

Comment: Have you considered using Vector class from System.Numerics?

Comment: @RickDavin yes i started out with `System.Numerics` but ran into some limitations, so now i am building my own to circumvent those. But for what i have atm it looks similar to `System.Numerics`, but i hope to change that soon :)

Comment: Could you name the limitations?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 6 → 3

Comment: @FutureCake could you tell the limitations you encountered with the `System.Numerics.Vector<>` class?

Comment: @t3chb0t I will try to explain what i was missing in the `System.numerics` namespace. First of all i wanted to be able to implicitly convert vectors between types to go from `Vector3` to `Vector2`, I wanted some extra constructors, A bunch of methods that don't exist in the `Numerics` vector.  And A vector of user defined length, Generics that i still have to make :) And probably some other stuff i cant think of right now... And most of all it is a great learning exercise :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are inconsistent with your use of the `this.` 'suffix'. Nobody can agree on this, but you should try to be consistent without projects.

---

I would remove the return values from every method which modifies `Vector3`: you have 2 copies of `Min`, and one is very confusing. All of the methods which happen to produce a vector (e.g. `Abs`, `Min`, Max`) happen to modify`this`and then return`this`. This is, in my opinion, a terrible API, and inconsistent with operations (like`Length`) which just happen to _not_ produce a vector. Anyone looking at the signature will assume it does not modify the vector, and you just open yourself to all the nightmares associated with mutable`struct`s. Do not mix an immutable/mutable API like you are now, because it will only infuriate your consumers.

Methods like `UpdateFromArray` are for some reason returning `this` as well.

---

You seem to be trying to provide a consistent API between `VectorX` (which I would just call `Vector`) and `Vector3`, so you might consider an `IVector` interface.

`VectorCount` is a mildly confusing name. It's the element count, or the length of the vector.

---

I would suggest not using `Math.Pow(, 2)` just to square something: even if it is optimised to detect this exact case (I don't know), it is just harder to read than `X * X`. I would rewrite `Dist` as `(this - other).length` for the sake of simplicity.

It's also common to provide a `LengthSquared` member which returns the sum before the squareroot, since often this is all that is needed and saves an expensive operation.

---

The parameter names for `Min` and `Max` are odd: `other` would be fine, but again I don't like the API.

---

I would expect `public Vector3(float[] arr)` to throw a nice exception if `arr` is null, or had a length other than 3.

It's good that most of your methods in `VectorX` are performing range checks (I didn't notice any that didn't). You don't need to put the 'non-exceptional' code in an else for these.

---

`VectorX` has many constructors which just provide 'defaults' for others. I would make these call directly the more general versions. E.g.

```
public VectorX(int vectorCount) : this(vectorCount, default(float))
{ }

public VectorX(params float[] values) : this(values, 0, values.Length)
{ }
```

This will significantly reduce redundancy and so improve maintainability.

---

Your `ToString` methods could be nicer: I would use string interpolation for `Vector3` (i.e. `$"<{X}, {Y}, {Z}>"`) and you should use a `StringBuilder` for `VectorX` (currently `VectorX.ToString()` is a quadratic memory operation when it should be linear).

---

> // do these size comparisions make sense?

No, I would say no; though, it does atleast provide an ordering, so it could be much worse.

The comparisons are also performing 2 unnecessary square-roots (you could compare the `LengthSquared`).

All your `Vector3` comparisions also include a completely redundant ternay clause, which will just get in the way of maintaince efforts and provide a greater surface overwhich bugs can will appear.

I would consider describing negatives in terms of the positives, e.g.

```
public static bool operator !=(Vector3 left, Vector3 right)
{
    return !(left == right);
}
```

---

Why isn't `VectorX.Equals(VectorX other)` implemented? What is the point of declaring you implement `IEquatable<VectorX>` if you do not?

---

I don't like all your single-line `if`s and `else`s. Even if you don't want to add braces, a line at the end of the condition or `else` helps significantly with readbility, and reduces the amount of code which is 'off side'.

---

All of your types and methods would benefit from inline documention (`///`). This would help to explain the confusing bits of the API, and clarify what methods like `Length` and `Normalise` mean.

---

> ```
> VectorValues[i] = (VectorValues[i] < 0) ? VectorValues[i] *= -1 :
> VectorValues[i];
> ```

What is wrong with `Math.Abs(VectorValues[i])`.

---

> `public int VectorCount { get { return 3; } }`

This can be made a little more concise:

```
public int VectorCount => 3;
```

You could do the same with the `static` `Unit` and `Zero` members.

---

You have some odd line-spacing in places (e.g. around `VectorX.NewUnit`). I can see no reason for this, so it just looks untidy and makes the code harder to scan.

---

Consider using an indexer instead of the `SetAt` and `GetAt` methods. These could be part of the `IVector` interface also.

---

`VectorX.VectorValues` should not be mutable, and probably shouldn't  be public. At the moment it is possible for someone to change `VectorValues` such that `VectorCount` will be wrong, or even to change it `null` and wreck everything. Hide it away so that people can't shoot themselves in the foot with your API.

You could re-write `VectorX.VectorCount` in terms of `VectorValues` to reduce redunancy and simplify the constructors.

```
public int VectorCount => VectorValues.Length;
```

Less redundancy again means there is less to go wrong, which makes the code easier to maintain.

---

The `VectorX(VectorX)` constructor is not good: all the other constructors duplicate the array they are given, but this just copies the reference. There is no point in this constructor (it's the same as a value-copy) and it will only create confusion. If instead it copied the array, then it would be fine.

```
public VectorX(VectorX vector) : this(vector.VectorValues)
{ }
```

`ToArray` would also imply a copy, and with `VectorValues` public does nothing useful. It should take a copy. This is as easy as `VectorValues.ToArray()` if you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your file. The fact that it does/doesn't copy should be in the documention.

---

I'm going to stop for now, but I may add to this answer when I have time, though I'm sure someone else will take up the slack long before then if there is more to be said.

Comment: It will be hard writing a _complement_ answer without having some kind of _intersection_  with this answer :p

Comment: About the status of `Pow(x, 2)`, it is not (yet) optimized by the main implementations, there is an [open issue for coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/26434), so maybe someday

Comment: VisualMelon, Thank you so much for the extensive list of improvements!!! As you may have seen from my code i am no pro ;) But this sure as hell will help with my improvement of skills :) I will be working on this list in the next few days probably :) Please keep adding indeed if you feel like it :)

Comment: @FutureCake you're welcome. It's customary to hold off before marking any answer as 'the' answer for at least a day or two, so as not to discourage more answers. I didn't add it to my answer, because it's not something I have much experience with, but you may want to look into the [SIMD](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-jit-finally-proposed-jit-and-simd-are-getting-married/) support in .NET if you really want serious performance.

Comment: @VisualMelon I unchecked the answer, i will get back to it in a few days then :) And i will go and check out what SIMD is! Thanks again!

Comment: You didn't mention the _new_  `readonly struct`, or I missed it. This would cure all of the mutability issues already on the compile level.

Comment: @t3chb0t I had a section about mutability, but frankly that would remove most of the API (so I removed it). Please do write your own answer about that (if you want), because I won't be adding it.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I think I found something noteworthy not yet mentioned by VisualMelon.

You are already using `MathF` to perform some operations for you, why not redirect some others to `Math`?

> ```
> public Vector3 Min(Vector3 min)
> {
>     this.X = (this.X < min.X) ? this.X : min.X;
>     this.Y = (this.Y < min.Y) ? this.Y : min.Y;
>     this.Z = (this.Z < min.Z) ? this.Z : min.Z;
>     return this;
> }
> ```

could be written as:

```
public Vector3 Min(Vector3 min)
{
    this.X = Math.Min(this.X, min.X);
    this.Y = Math.Min(this.Y, min.Y);
    this.Z = Math.Min(this.Z, min.Z);
    return this;
}
```

You could do the equivalent for method `Max`.

Note an inconsistency or at least a very confusing meaning of the variables `min` and `max`. In methods `Min` and `Max` you take the min, respectively max of the current value with the provided value. While in `Clamp` you turn the meaning of min and max around.

I would refactor `Min` and `Max` to use the same definition for min and max as `Clamp`. This way, the provided variable is a boundary, just as in `Clamp`.

```
public Vector3 Min(Vector3 max)
{
    this.X = Math.Min(this.X, max.X);
    this.Y = Math.Min(this.Y, max.Y);
    this.Z = Math.Min(this.Z, max.Z);
    return this;
}

public Vector3 Max(Vector3 min)
{
    this.X = Math.Max(this.X, min.X);
    this.Y = Math.Max(this.Y, min.Y);
    this.Z = Math.Max(this.Z, min.Z);
    return this;
}
```

Clamp could then be rewritten (you could also add some validation that max > min):

```
public Vector3 Clamp(Vector3 min, Vector3 max)
{
    this.Max(min);
    this.Min(max);
    return this;
}
```

One other thing about the original `Clamp` code:

> ```
> public Vector3 Clamp(Vector3 min, Vector3 max)
> {
>     this.X = (this.X < min.X) ? min.X : this.X = (this.X > max.X) ? max.X : this.X;
>     this.Y = (this.Y < min.Y) ? min.Y : this.Y = (this.Y > max.Y) ? max.Y : this.Y;
>     this.Z = (this.Z < min.Z) ? min.Z : this.Z = (this.Z > max.Z) ? max.Z : this.Z;
>     return this;
> }
> ```

You don't have to assign this.* to itself in the ternary operations. You could simplify to:

```
public Vector3 Clamp(Vector3 min, Vector3 max)
{
    this.X = (this.X < min.X) ? min.X : (this.X > max.X) ? max.X : this.X;
    this.Y = (this.Y < min.Y) ? min.Y : (this.Y > max.Y) ? max.Y : this.Y;
    this.Z = (this.Z < min.Z) ? min.Z : (this.Z > max.Z) ? max.Z : this.Z;
    return this;
}
```

Or a bit more compact using `Math`:

```
public Vector3 Clamp(Vector3 min, Vector3 max)
{
    this.X = Math.Min(Math.Max(this.X, min.X), max.X);
    this.Y = Math.Min(Math.Max(this.Y, min.Y), max.Y);
    this.Z = Math.Min(Math.Max(this.Z, min.Z), max.Z);
    return this;
}
```

Beyond this, I would also favor to use immutable classes. So instead of changing the instance coordinates, I would create a new instance of a `Vector3` instead. If the entire API is written this way, your fluent methods make sense and would consistently return new instances on chaining.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the advice! Just one question about the using of `Math.Min, Math.Max` etc. Isn't this less efficient because then i am first calling an other class which calls a method and then returns the result? Instead of just doing it with statements? Or is the difference negligible?

Comment: The performance penalty of calling another method is negligible, as you say :) usability and reusability should definately be favored here